# ggplot "error in rename"

Tags: r, ggplot2

*update* I have posted my solution below, the culprit was my own `rename` function that overrode `reshape::rename`

---

I have been using the ggplot R package with little trouble until today. Today, I get an error using code that has previously worked, and when I debug it to the minimal working example, it still gives an error;

If I do this:

```
library(ggplot2)
d<- data.frame(x=1:3,y=1:3)
ggplot(data=d) + geom_line(aes(x,y))
```

The following error is returned:

```
Error in rename(x, .base_to_ggplot) : 
  unused argument(s) (.base_to_ggplot)
```

The traceback is:

```
6: rename(x, .base_to_ggplot)
5: rename_aes(aes)
4: aes()
3: structure(list(data = data, layers = list(), scales = Scales$new(), 
       mapping = mapping, options = list(), coordinates = CoordCartesian$new(), 
       facet = FacetGrid$new(), plot_env = environment), class = "ggplot")
2: ggplot.data.frame(data = d, aes = c(x, y))
1: ggplot(data = d, aes = c(x, y))
```

The error does not occur after removing all objects using `rm(list=ls())`, but it is still not clear to me what object is causing this error or why - how can I figure this out?

Does anyone know what may have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused because ggplot2 doesn't use namespaces - this will be fixed in the next release.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not able to return the same error message that you've posted above. When running your code snippet, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: geom_pointrange requires the following missing aesthetics: ymin, ymax
```

Accordingly, `geom_pointrange()` is expecting arguments for `ymin` and `ymax`. I'll leave it up to you to fill in your pertinent information for what should go into those parameters, but this code executes:

`ggplot(data=d) + geom_pointrange(aes(x,y, ymin = y - .5, ymax = y + .5))`

Comment: sorry for that. I wrote the example quickly instead of copying it from my terminal. I get the error with geom_line, and I have changed the example code.

Comment: @David - doh! My apologies. However, I am able to execute the updated code fine as well. Sounds like it may be something in your environment that is causing issues...and I'm probably not the best to help in that arena. Can you reproduce the problem if you start a new instance of R with a blank environment?

Comment: no, I can't reproduce the error... and I can get it not to reproduce by `rm(list=ls())`. At least I have something to chew on for debugging.

Comment: @David - I'd probably start with looking at the `str()` of the object you are trying to model and make sure it is as you expect it to be...as you know ggplot2 expects dataframes. Or maybe you have an object in your environment that is masking the name of a function that ggplot2 is trying to call upon?

Answer (score 1):

The error was caused by one of the objects (thanks to pointers from @Chase).

Here is how I debugged and found the culprit. The important part was to use the `try()` function that keeps the for loop running despite errors

```
foo <- ls() #get a static list of all suspect objects
for(i in 1:length(foo)) {
    print(foo[i])
    rm(list=foo[i])
    try(ggplot()+geom_point(aes(x=1:2,y=1:2)))
}
```

This resulted in the following output:

```
...
[1] "45 reg.model"
Error in rename(x, .base_to_ggplot) : 
  unused argument(s) (.base_to_ggplot)
[1] "46 reg.parms"
Error in rename(x, .base_to_ggplot) : 
  unused argument(s) (.base_to_ggplot)
[1] "47 rename"
[1] "48 samples"
...
```

aha! it was my own function `rename` that caused the error, since `ggplot2` relies on `reshape::rename`.

Solution: rename the new `rename` function... how to prevent this in the future? Perhaps study up on the use of namespaces.

Comment: I like your use of `ls()` for the debugging, I wouldn't have thought on that. Glad it worked out!